# SPO - Remove or Disable the Group By metadata change

Tags: sharepoint-online, grouping

In a list I've created a custom form and disabled the option for user to do edits through quick edit or information pane. There is a workflow running on the background that gets the corresponding approvals, and the idea is that the Status is only modified through the workflow and not through input.

My problem with this is, anyone who can contribute into the item (Requestors and Approvers) can potentially change this through the use of the **Group By Metadata change on drag and drop** (This means, if I group by Status, and I drop an item with Status = New into the Status = Approved... it is updated to Approved).

Is there a way I can disable this? Or can you think of a possible solution?

The only thing I can come up with at this point is to change requestors permissions into read only after creation and hope that approvers know better, but this is definitely not the desired state.

Thank you.

Edit: I'm thinking out loud here, is it possible to create an SPFx package that takes and extends the default behaviour for **group by metadata change on drag and drop** through the different categories for that list in particular. Is this something doable?

Comment: I don't want to block answers to this if there is a way. For the time being, I'm forcing the list to go to Classic, and hiding the option to exit classic experience through CSS. I hate security by obscurity because if someone really wants they will get there. Any help, guidance or new ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this on my tenant and found some strange behavior. Below is a workaround you could try:

**Step 1:**

When you group by 'Status' but do not include it as part of the displayed view columns the user will not be able to drag and drop. In the below image, the library view is grouped by 'Status' but it is not part of the actual list view columns. It did not allow me to move the files in this case.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Now the user could go to Add column -> Show/hide columns and add the 'Status' column to the view. At this point, the user will still not be able to drag and drop items between groups.

**Step 3:**

However, if the user now clicks on 'Status' column ->  Group by Status, then the user will be able to drag and drop items between groups which will update the status column.

You could stop at **Step 1** or **Step 2** and hope the user does not implement Step 3.

Comment: In my testing it doesn't happen on either of the 3 cases, but it does work for changing on my soon to be production list. This frightens me to implement since its not the expected or documented behaviour and can change/be fixed moving forward.

Comment: I should have started with... thank you very much for testing this out and bringing a possible solution to this thread. If it had been the documented way to proceed making sure it wouldn't break moving forward I would've definitely awarded the bounty. I think I will have to do extra research on the SPFx to extend the functionality and avoid it breaking moving forward

Comment: Completely agree with you that it is not a reliable solution

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it is possible to disable this function.

It is what “Group By” do in SharePoint lists, as a filter.

Comment: I don't mind having it as a filter, what I don't like is that it can potentially modify metadata even when I've taken all the steps to avoid this happening. I think I'll have to revert the list into the Classic Experience. 

The problem now looks like users are able to switch even when you are forcing that to be the default experience, out of 2 lists one gives me the option and the other doesn't. Weird.

Comment: @Yugo Yes, it’s kind of a known issue in SharePoint Online. I’ve edited the reply to add reference on how to hide the option with CSS code.

Comment: I didn't ask for that since I know how to do it but thank you, this is not the answer I was looking for though. BTW, you should never modify the default MasterPage, I would urge you to delete or rephrase that so that people who don't know better don't go ahead and modify that one.

Comment: @Yugo Deleted. I'll drop it then.